# match each use of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm working on a todo list application where the user can add to do list items to a web page, and also search for to do list items. Below I'm working on the search function. Right now what happens is that I add an li item to the page that says "you found" + the name the user searches under + the task that matches that particular item. But, what I'm not sure how to do is to match for every list item where that name is used. For instance I could have someone named Bob doing three different tasks. Right now this search will only match the first one, but I would like to match all three. Any suggestions?

```
function search() {
   var searchTerm = document.getElementById("search").value;
   searchTerm = searchTerm.trim();

   if(searchTerm == null || searchTerm == "") {
   alert("Please enter a string to search for");
   return;
   }
   else {
     var todoObj = undefined;
     results = undefined;
     re = undefined;

   for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
     todoObj = todos[i];
     re = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
     resultsOne = todoObj.who.match(re);
     if(resultsOne) {
       var ul = document.getElementById("test");
       var li = document.createElement(li);
       li.className = "listItem";  
       li.innerHTML = "You found " + todoObj.who + " who needs to " + todoObj.task; 
       ul.appendChild(li);    
       }
      }      
     }    
    }
```

Comment: It looks to me like it should work. Each match creates a new LI and appends it to the UL. Can you create a fiddle demonstrating it?

Comment: It looks like you're performing the search match at each iteration of the `for` loop and then displaying the result immediately. Might I suggest you keep a list of the todo's that matched, then finally at the end output your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a temporary list of the todo's that matched, then finally, at the end, output your results:

```
var matchedTodos = []; // temporary list of matched todos

for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
     todoObj = todos[i];
     re = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
     resultsOne = todoObj.who.match(re);
     if(resultsOne) {
         // found a match, add it to our temporary list
         matchedTodos.push(todoObj);
     }
 } 

// now output the matched todos

if (matchedTodos.length > 0) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("test");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "listItem";  
    var tasks = '';
    var todoObj = null;
    for(var j = 0; j < matchedTodos.length; j++) {
        todoObj = matchedTodos[j];
        tasks += todoObj.task + ', ';
    }
    li.innerHTML = "You found " + todoObj.who + " who needs to " + tasks; 
    ul.appendChild(li);  
}
```

You want the output to be something like `"You found Bob who needs to clean his room, take a bath, sleep"`. You will have to add some logic for getting the correct number of `,` commas for the sentence to be correct :P

*Edit:* To have them all as individual list items:

```
var matchedTodos = []; // temporary list of matched todos

for(var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
     todoObj = todos[i];
     re = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
     resultsOne = todoObj.who.match(re);
     if(resultsOne) {
         // found a match, add it to our temporary list
         matchedTodos.push(todoObj);
     }
 } 

// now output the matched todos

if (matchedTodos.length > 0) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("test");
    var todoObj = null;
    for(var j = 0; j < matchedTodos.length; j++) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "listItem";  
        todoObj = matchedTodos[j];
        li.innerHTML = "You found " + todoObj.who + " who needs to " + todoObj.task;
        ul.appendChild(li);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: this is great but I think I'm supposed to add each as a separate list item

Comment: What difference does it make whether you display the matches during the search or at the end?

Comment: @Barmar In his question, his code has him creating the `ul` element inside each iteration of the loop. So the solution would be to only create that `ul` when there are matched items, then include each matched todo `li` elements into it. Can't do this in one-pass because you wouldn't know if there was ANY match until after the `for` loop has finished going through the list.

Comment: His code doesn't create the `ul` element at all. It's already in the DOM, and he just assigns it to a variable with `getElementById()`. It's a little inefficient because it does this for every match, but that shouldn't change the effect.